# list of users and their UUID in a jazz project area

Tags: rtc

Greetings for the day

I want to retrieve the UUID of individual member in the project can any one help me by providing me the url.(OSLC or nonOSLC).

Note: Im not using any RTC Java API.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the right url is to display the page which lists the members and admins

```
https://your.jazz.server/ccm/admin#action=com.ibm.team.process.editProjectArea&itemId=_your_project_area_id
```

And use the [Chome DevTool Network view](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) to see all the url used when that page is loading.

I see for instance a url using projectAreaByUUIDWithLimitedMembers.
See this [perl script](https://jazz.net/wiki/pub/Deployment/ListingProjectAreaMembershipinRTCRQM/clmProjectUsersPull.pl.txt) which uses the same service url

```perl
# Different URI's for main project area vs team area, very reasonable assumption that we wont hit a project/team area with more than 100K users
  if ($projects{$projectArea}{'itemId'} eq $areaItemId) {
    $URI = $jazzURI . "/service/com.ibm.team.process.internal.service.web.IProcessWebUIService/projectAreaByUUIDWithLimitedMembers?processAreaItemId=" . $areaItemId . "&maxMembers=100000";
  }
```